# Proving divisibility with sum

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

Claim:

> Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$.
>
> If $(x + y) | z$ and $(x + z) | y$, then $(y + z) | x$

How can I prove/disprove this?

Comment: This looks false.  Take $x=3, y=z=-2$.  Then $x+y=x+z=1$ so the first two tests are satisfied.  But $y+z=-4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to find counter examples, if you do not see some obvious ones:

$\begin{cases} 
(x+y)\mid z\iff z=a(x+y)\\
(x+z)\mid y\iff y=b(x+z)\\
\end{cases}$

$y+z=ax+ay+bx+bz=(a+b)x+ay+bz=(a+b)x+ab(2x+y+z)=(a+b+2ab)x+ab(y+z)$

So we have the condition $(1-ab)(y+z)=(a+b+2ab)x$

For $(y+z)$ to divide $x$ we requires that $c=\frac{1-ab}{a+b+2ab}$ is an integer.

From there, choose values of $a,b$ that do not fulfil this condition and you'll get a counter example.

For instance $a=1,b=2$ then $c=-\frac 17$ not an integer.

Now solve the system

$\begin{cases} z=1(x+y)\\ y=2(x+z)\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases} y=-4x \\ z=-3x\end{cases}\quad$ and triplet $(-1,4,3)$ does not work.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

How about verifying this for some simple fixed values of $y$, e.g. for $y=1$?

Answer (score 0):

$x = -1, \: y = 2, \: z = 3$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Nice, but could you please write down your thought process to come up with this counterexample? I really couldn't think of that example

Comment: We want to disprove that something divides $x$, so it seems a good start to choose $x = \pm 1$, let's say $x = -1$. Now we want $y$, $z$ to satisfy $y - 1 \mid z$ and $z - 1 \mid y$. The simplest choice is $y = 2$, so that the first divisibility holds for every $z$; then we are left with the condition $z - 1 \mid 2$ and here the obvious choice is $z = 3$. Now since $x + y = 5 \nmid -1$ this example does indeed work, as desired.